# How do I get character entities to render (PHP pulling from database to display in Fullcalendar)?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, fullcalendar

I'm using PHP to pull posts from Wordpress (`WP_Query()`) to generate Fullcalendar event strings. All's working swell except character entities (specifically apostrophes), which are in the post's Title field (as apostrophes), are displaying on the webpage as "`&#8217;`". I thought maybe there's some double decoding going on somewhere, so I tried running the variable through `html_entity_decode()`, as well as `htmlspecialchars_decode()`, with no luck.  Thanks for any help!

```
<?php 
$the_film = ': '.strtoupper(get_the_title($filmID));
...
echo '{"id":"'.get_the_ID().'","title":"'.$the_city.$the_film.'","start":"'.$start.'","color":"'.$color.'","textColor":"'.$textColor.'","url":"'.$filmlink.'","moderator":"'.$moderator.'","guest":"'.$guest.'"},';
 ?>
```

Comment: Check your encoding type from wordpress and your app client side, i'm sure you can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the nudge, Henrique. Your confidence in me proved worthy. I messed around with things a bit more and because I was using .text() rather than .html() in rendering my FC events, the character entities weren't being decoded.